bundle transaction in bsc with contract address
i want to build bsc bundle like this contract address
here is example
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x934ad8417862a1e1e81a5b7ec4558f89877f06c33d3b2612293272eba437c869
https://bscscan.com/address/0x281a148309de23d0132a3932d2e14b6a9cefc501
i want to deploy contract but code is bytecode , not verify
here byte code
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

i have someone can help me, i want to rescue my hacked wallet

Using a contract's bytecode directly without verification poses significant risks because you cannot be sure of its security or functionality. When the bytecode is not verified, you lack the source code to understand what the contract does, which could expose you to potential vulnerabilities or malicious behavior.
You can try to use decompilation tools to attempt to understand what the bytecode does, but this is not always accurate or reliable.

So, for example, how do I create a contract address like this? https://bscscan.com/address/0x281a148309de23d0132a3932d2e14b6a9cefc501

oh yes, thank you, maybe I'll try later,
but I can ask for one more thing
please make a simple code to do something like this https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6452f0d9f9c69ddb3ab85b02e2827828c47c31e9c595922ac4ea22252effea4f I want to try the Fantom network, I want to save my account which was hit by a sweeper bot, because the Fantom network doesn't have a bundle yet
